# How to bind command on entire Grid LeftClick in WPF User Control

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, desktop-application

I want to achieve Grid Left Click inside a user control.

My WPF User Control

```
  <Grid>
       <Border Grid.Row="0" CornerRadius="7" >
            <Border.Background>
                <SolidColorBrush Color="#ffffff" Opacity="0.08"></SolidColorBrush>
            </Border.Background>
            <Grid>
                <Image Source="/Assets/Images/Icon/ic-add.png" Width="70" Height="70"/>
            </Grid>
        </Border>
 </Grid>
```

Here is my Window

```
<Grid>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
        <usercontrols:CreateNewProfile Width="200" Height="235" Margin="40,40,0,0"> 
        </usercontrols:CreateNewProfile>           
    </<StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

There is a command Called CreateNewProfile

Very straight question How to bind command on Left Click of User Control?

Comment: Use a Button instead of a UserControl. It's unclear why you are having a UserControl at all. There is just an Image in a Border. The Grids seem to be redundant.

Comment: Hi @Clemens I do want to use in multiple places

Comment: Create and reuse an appropriate Button Style resource.

Comment: I have just included a small part, in reality, it will behave according to data There will be a list of user profiles on click of it something gonna happen so That's the reason I am using  User Control

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use InputBindings inside of your UserControl:

```
    <Grid.InputBindings>
        <MouseBinding MouseAction="LeftClick" Command="{Binding CreateNewProfile}"/>
    </Grid.InputBindings>
```

Comment: Hi @tomáš-buchta UserControl will not be having DataContext